# I want to use tab key to make four spaces in django textarea?

Tags: django, tabs, textarea

in django textarea, it need four spaces to highlight.
i want to use a tab to replace it .
but it jumps to another tags,
I wonder if there is any solution to it.

Comment: This is in no way a question about Django. Django doesn't control your browser's input behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would require a JavaScript widget that captures the input event. What happens when a key is pressed is up to the browser (that is, totally out of your control), so without writing a key capturing widget of your own the default behavior (that is, "move to next control") is what will happen.

It is useful to keep in mind that the web is not actually an application platform (its a document publication platform) and browsers are not actually window managers (they are document viewers).